# How do I filter data with the same title from an array of objects?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

I have been trying to put up with the following behaviour for pending checks:
[image]

Instead I have been only able to do as follows:
[image]

My data looks like follow:
[image]

[image]

The code that I have written uptil now is as follows:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  ActivityIndicator,
  StyleSheet,
  SafeAreaView,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
  FlatList,
} from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
import {ROOT} from '../../services/ApiUrl';
import {vc} from '../../api';
import {timestamp} from '../../utils/dateUtils';
import {Images} from '../../assets/index';
export default function NutritionAssessment(props) {
  const {navigation} = props;
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  const [pendingIndex, setPendingIndex] = useState(null);
  const [questionsData, setQuestionsData] = useState({});
  const [idd, setIdd] = useState(null);
  const [optionid, setOptionId] = useState([]);
  const [group, setGroup] = useState(null);
  // console.log(props.route.params?.id);
  const id = props.route.params?.id;
  // console.log('id', id);
  // const getQuestions = async () => {
  //   const response = await API.get(
  //     `/wellchild/nutri-check?screen_type=116&child_id=${id}&vc=${vc}`,
  //   );
  //   console.log('nutrition response', response.data.content);
  //   setQuestionsData(response.data.content);
  //   setPendingIndex(questionsData.questions.length - 1);
  // };
  const getQuestions = () => {
    axios
      .get(
        `${ROOT}/wellchild/nutri-check?screen_type=116&child_id=${id}&vc=${vc}`,
      )
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log('nutrition response', response.data.content);
        setQuestionsData(response.data.content);
        setPendingIndex(response.data.content.questions.length - 1);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getQuestions();
  }, []);

  const post = (item) => {
    console.log('ITEM', item);
    let chosen_option_id = optionid.concat(item.id);
    setOptionId(chosen_option_id);
    axios
      .post(`${ROOT}/wellchild/nutri-check/answer?screen_type=116&vc=55`, {
        answer_type: item.type,
        assessment_age: questionsData.assessment_age,
        child_id: id,
        chosen_option_id: optionid,
        event_date: timestamp,
        question_id: item.id,
        score: item.score,
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
  const renderItem = ({item}) => {
   
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={Styles.options}
          onPress={() => SelectOption(item)}>
          <Text style={Styles.optionText}>{item.name}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  };
  const SelectOption = (item) => {
    console.log('selected', item);
    console.log('set ID', idd);
    if (index === questionsData.questions.length - 1) {
      navigation.navigate('nutritionassessmentreport', {
        id: id,
        assessment_age: questionsData.assessment_age,
      });
    } else {
      setIndex(index + 1);
      setPendingIndex(pendingIndex - 1);
    }
    post(item);
    console.log('incremented index', index);
    console.log('decreased index', pendingIndex);
    // console.log('length',questionsData.questions.length)
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        padding: 16,
      }}>
      {questionsData &&
      questionsData != {} &&
      questionsData != null &&
      questionsData != '' &&
      questionsData != undefined
        ? questionsData.questions &&
          questionsData.questions != '' &&
          questionsData.questions != undefined &&
          questionsData.questions != null &&
          questionsData.questions.length > 0 && (
            <View style={{alignItems: 'center', height: '100%', padding: 10}}>
              <Text style={Styles.title}>
                {questionsData.questions[index].title}
              </Text>
              <Text style={Styles.text}>
                {questionsData.questions[index].text}
              </Text>
              <FlatList
                renderItem={renderItem}
                data={questionsData.questions[index].options}
              />

              {pendingIndex != null && pendingIndex != undefined && (
                <View style={{marginTop: 100, alignItems: 'center'}}>
                  <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                    <Text style={Styles.pendingIndex}>{pendingIndex}</Text>
                    <Text style={{marginLeft: 7, fontSize: 12}}>
                      Pending Checks
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                  <Image
                    source={Images.pendingchecks}
                    style={{width: 60, height: 60, marginTop: 17}}
                  />
                </View>
              )}

              {console.log('decreased index.....', pendingIndex)}
            </View>
          )
        : null}
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
const Styles = StyleSheet.create({
  title: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 16,
    color: '#000',
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 16,
    marginTop: 21,
    marginBottom: 30,
    fontWeight: '600',
  },
  options: {
    borderRadius: 40,
    height: 40,
    padding: 25,
    width: 300,
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderColor: '#000',

    borderWidth: 0.8,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginBottom: 20,
  },

  pendingIndex: {
    fontSize: 12,
    color: '#D32F2F',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  optionText: {
    fontSize: 14,
    color: '#000',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  optionSelectedText: {
    fontSize: 14,
    color: '#fff',
  },
});
```

Am really stuck with how to implement the expected behaviour which is with every same title in the array of objects->that would be grouped together and the answers selected for that particular group would be decremented one by one from the group.length then it moves to the next group.

I hope am able to make myself clear, any help would be great

Comment: I am not exactly sure about this but I have one idea: Store the questions in a seperate object with only titles (such as questionsToBeAnswered). If the question is anwered, you can check if it exists on the new object and if true, you can remove it. Your pending request number will be the length of that object.

Comment: @SinanYaman could you please add some code?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
const groupedBytitle = {};

questions.forEach(question => {
  groupedBytitle.hasOwnProperty(question.title)
    ? groupedBytitle[question.title].push(question)
    : (groupedBytitle[question.title] = [question]);
});
```

This will group your questions by title

```
{
title : [question, question],
title2: [question],
title3: [question, question, question]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to get number of questions for selected group.

```
const totalQuestions = questionsData.filter(item => item.group === selectedGroup).length;
```

this will give you the number of questions for the selected group. where
selectedGroup should be the selected group key value (allergies).

Now you need to know how many question you have answered.

```
const numberOfQuestionsRemaining = totalQuestions.filter(item => item.isAnswer != true).length;
```

totalQuestions will be array of questions for the selected group. you have filtered the array and get the number of questions which are not answered yet.

you need to do one thing. After you answer any single question, you need to add a key in your question object. > isAnswer = true;
it will keep that the question has been answer.

Comment: you could have maintain the array of answered questions. but i don't think there is any unique identifier on which basis you can determine whether the question has been answered or not. that's why i suggest you to append a key `isAnswer: true` after you answer the question.